# Passing http request header to RestAPI from SpringXD using http-client processor

Tags: http-headers, spring-xd

I am trying to hit a rest api from my http-client processor module.
I would like to know how can I send request header to the url I am trying to hit.
Without the request header I get 500 Internal Server Error.

Will mappedRequestHeaders option be useful to pass headers, can someone give an example please.

Below is how my stream looks like :

```
jms --destination= | http-client --url='''https://hostname:11210/cards/accounts?eName=John%20Smith&caFSix=426600&caLF=1234''' --httpMethod=GET | log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming your header is `x-foo`, set the `mappedRequestHeaders` property of the `http-client` processor to `"HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, x-foo"`.

Then, if the inbound JMS message has a header `x-foo=bar`, it will be mapped in the `http-client`.

This assumes you are using a local or rabbit message bus; for redis you would have to configure the bus to pass your header.

If the inbound JMS message doesn't have the header, you will need a custom processor (or a customized `http-client`) to use a `<header-enricher/>` to add the header.

**EDIT**:

You can use redis, but you need to add your header name to the servers.yml config for redis if you want them to traverse the bus:

```
xd:
  messagebus:
    redis:
      headers:
```

However if you add a header-enricher directly in your custom http-client, they won't need to pass over the bus.

You can use json path to extract the content from your JMS message. If you also need to change the payload, you may find it easier to use a custom transformer to create the message.

```
Message<?> transform(Message<String> msg) {

   return MessageBuilder.withPayload(newPayload)
             .copyHeaders(msg)
             .setHeader("accept", "...")
             .setHeader(...)
             . ...
             .build();
}
```

**EDIT#2**:

I just tested it and it worked fine for me...

```
<header-enricher input-channel="input" output-channel="toHttp">
    <header name="foo" value="bar" />
</header-enricher>

<channel id="toHttp" />

<int-http:outbound-gateway id='http-client'
    request-channel='toHttp' url-expression="${url}" http-method="${httpMethod}"
    expected-response-type='java.lang.String' charset='${charset}'
    reply-timeout='${replyTimeout}' reply-channel='output'
    mapped-request-headers="${mappedRequestHeaders}"
    mapped-response-headers="${mappedResponseHeaders}">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<channel id="output" />
<channel id="input" />
```

With this stream definition...

```
xd:>stream create ticktock --definition "time --fixedDelay=5 | http-client --url='''http://localhost:8080/http/receiveGateway''' --mappedRequestHeaders=HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,foo | log --expression=#root" --deploy
```

...with these results...

```
18:02:20,284  INFO task-scheduler-3 sink.ticktock - GenericMessage [payload=2015-02-02 18:02:20 from the other side, headers={Server=Apache-Coyote/1.1, foo=bar, connection=keep-alive, id=8a444177-b96d-70c3-58e7-d92067d6b18e, Content-Length=39, contentType=text/plain, http_statusCode=200, Date=1422918140000, timestamp=1422918140284}]
18:02:25,292  INFO task-scheduler-3 sink.ticktock - GenericMessage [payload=2015-02-02 18:02:25 from the other side, headers={Server=Apache-Coyote/1.1, foo=bar, connection=keep-alive, id=d62b46ed-dcc7-6dd0-35ea-b7b988c4f2f1, Content-Length=39, contentType=text/plain, http_statusCode=200, Date=1422918145000, timestamp=1422918145292}]
```

As you can see, `foo=bar` appears in the final message.

Now, in the HTTP message, by default, the user-defined headers get prefixed by `X-` so the `foo` header shows up as `X-foo: bar` in HTTP.

In order to suppress the `X-`, you need another tweak to the `http-client`...

```
<header-enricher input-channel="input" output-channel="toHttp">
    <header name="foo" value="bar" />
</header-enricher>

<channel id="toHttp" />

<int-http:outbound-gateway id='http-client'
    request-channel='toHttp' url-expression="${url}" http-method="${httpMethod}"
    expected-response-type='java.lang.String' charset='${charset}'
    reply-timeout='${replyTimeout}' reply-channel='output'
    header-mapper="mapper">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<beans:bean id="mapper" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
    <beans:property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value="" />
    <beans:property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="${mappedRequestHeaders}" />
    <beans:property name="inboundHeaderNames" value="${mappedResponseHeaders}" />
</beans:bean>

<channel id="output" />
<channel id="input" />
```

Comment: Thanks much.  In my case the jms message will just have a  text and no JMS header. The text that this jms message contains will have the actual header required for calling the REST API on the url I am using in http-client processor (Its something like : `{"User-Agent": "Shred","Accept": "application/json"}`.    Did `x-foo=bar` in your answer mean a JMS header ?  I guess in my case I need to create a custom http-client as suggested by you to add the header.  Also I was using Redis, so I now moved on to use local message bus as suggested by you.

Comment: I added some more details.

Comment: I tried things as below, still could not pass the headers to my API. Can you please help.

Comment: You have two subscribers on `input`; the http gateway and the header enricher. You need to wire them in order `input->enricher->gateway->output` (use a new channel in the enricher's output-channel and gateway's request-channel).

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I corrected the xml to wire header-enricher and outbound-gateway still the headers do not reach my RESTApi. If you look at the groovy script I mentioned below , I am passing same headers from it as I am passing from this http-client processor and they seem to work with groovy. I am on singlenode, so redis is out of picture in removing headers. Is there any more configuration required in http-client to let it pass headers ?

Comment: Thanks a ton!! . I was able to make a call successfully to my RestAPI  by passing the headers. I was struggling for last few days but figured out a  really silly mistake. I did not modify `outbound-gateway` to  have `header-mapper="mapper"`. Thank you so much again !!

Answer (score 1):

@Gary As suggested by you, I did create a custom http-client with header-enricher as below :

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id='http-client'
            request-channel='headerenricheroutput' url-expression="${url}" http-method="${httpMethod}"
            expected-response-type='java.lang.String' charset='${charset}'
            reply-timeout='${replyTimeout}' reply-channel='output'
            mapped-request-headers="${mappedRequestHeaders}"
            mapped-response-headers="${mappedResponseHeaders}">
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>
    <channel id="output" />
    <channel id="headerenricheroutput" />
    <header-enricher input-channel="input" output-channel="headerenricheroutput">
            <header name="User-Agent" value="Shred"/>
            <header name="Api-Key" value="AbCdEFg1HiJ23klMnopQrS4U"/>
            <header name="Accept" value="application/json"/>
    </header-enricher>

    <channel id="input" />
```

I created a stream as : `stream create --name abc--definition "jms --destination=myQueue| http-client --url='''https://host:port/cards/accounts?eName=John%20Smith&cardFS=426600&cardLF=1234''' --mappedRequestHeaders=HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,User-Agent,Api-Key,Accept --httpMethod=GET | log" --deploy`

But still I could not pass header to the URL. Can you please point me to correct direction.

Meanwhile, just for the sake of getting a reply from my API, I created a groovy script to invoke the above URL with header and I was able to do it. Maybe someone will find it useful so posting it. The groovy script is :

`def json = "https://host:11210/credit/accounts?eName=John%20Smith&cardFS=426600&cardLF=1234".toURL().getText(requestProperties:['User-Agent': 'Shred', 'Api-Key': 'abc',  Accept: 'application/json'])`

The stream looks like :

```
jms --destination=tiki | transform --script=transform.groovy | log
```

Still I could not figure out what needs to be done exactly for http-client.