# How to send http-client post request with springXD

Tags: java, spring, spring-xd

I have implemented one restfull webservice project in my local From rest-client I can able to send request and also I am getting response.
Below is rest-client  "Post request":

```
{"address":{"type1":"abc","email":"tata@gmail.com"}}
```

Response:

```
{"address":{"type1":"abc","email":"tata@gmail.com"}}
```

And these are the headers.

```
Content-Type:application/json
```

Below one is my local java project API URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/test1
```

Now I am try to learning spring XD how I can send request with spring XD. I Have install Spring XD and RabbitMQ in my local.

Help me how to send post request from Spring XD with these json request.

Comment: You can create custom components for XD using Spring integration

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Spring, maybe you could use the class `org.springframework.web.clientRestTemplate` to request your API:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpEntity<MailContact> request = new HttpEntity<>(new MailContact("contact@mail.net"));
Contact contact = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/test/test1", request, Contact.class);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: using spring I can able to send request and getting response. I am trying Spring XD. How to send request with header using Spring-XD

Comment: So maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118990/passing-http-request-header-to-restapi-from-springxd-using-http-client-processor) can help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `httpMethod` property...

```
--httpMethod=POST
```

and `mappedRequestHeaders` to add your custom header, but it will get an `X-` prefix. You will need to customize the processor with a custom header mapper to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's give you example. If you want SpringXD to be webservice client getting response every minute from monday to friday between 8 am and 5 pm , and dump result to file,
Please run below command with your xd-shell

```
stream create --name my_rest_client --definition "trigger --cron='0 * 8-17 * * 1-5' | http-client --url='''http://localhost:8080/test/test1''' --replyTimeout=2000 --httpMethod=GET --outputType=text/plain | file" --deploy
```

trigger module will send '' char as default request , to change this behavior you can define exact string by adding payload param like:
trigger --payload='yourRequestMessage' --cron='0 * 8-17 * * 1-5'

Comment: I want to try POST method and need to send request body also instead of GET method.

Comment: abccccccccccccccccccccccc